# Masking FLV video in AS3 with PNG alpha channel

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, masking

I'm trying to mask an FLV with a PNG alpha channel. I'm using BitmapData (from a PNG) but it's not working. Is there anything I'm missing? Cut up code below:

```
var musclesLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var musclesContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
var musclesImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var musclesBitmapData:BitmapData;

var musclesVideo:Video = new Video(752, 451.2);
var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var stream:NetStream;

function loadMuscles():void {
    musclesLoader.load(new URLRequest('img/muscles.png'));
    musclesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, musclesComplete);
}

function musclesComplete():void {
    musclesBitmapData = new BitmapData(musclesLoader.content.width, musclesLoader.content.height, true, 0x000000);
    musclesImage.bitmapData = musclesBitmapData;
    musclesImage.smoothing = true;
    musclesContainer.addChild(musclesImage);
    contentContainer.addChild(musclesContainer);
}

function loadMusclesVideo():void {
    connection.connect(null);
    stream = new NetStream(connection);
    stream.client = this;
    musclesVideo.mask = musclesImage; 
    stage.addChild(musclesVideo);
    musclesVideo.attachNetStream(stream);
    stream.bufferTime = 1;
    stream.receiveAudio(true);
    stream.receiveVideo(true);
    stream.play("vid/muscles.flv");
}
```

Outside this code I have a function that adds the containers to the stage, etc and places the objects in the appropriate spots. It sort of works - the mask applies, but in a square (the size of the boundaries of musclesBitmapData) rather than with the shape of the alpha channel.

Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: if you're using the Flash IDE, as a test can you do it on the timeline? Just to see how the alpha channel works, maybe png is not the way to go, needs to be gif, etc. On the other hand, also to clear up confusion, work using a base graphic instead of the .flv, just to avoid any potential problems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_28.html):

> **Alpha channel masking**
>
> Alpha channel masking is supported if
>   both the mask and the masked display
>   objects use bitmap caching, as shown
>   here:

```
// maskShape is a Shape instance which includes a gradient fill. 
mySprite.cacheAsBitmap = true;
maskShape.cacheAsBitmap = true;
mySprite.mask = maskShape;
```

which means that, unless you can cache your flv as a bitmap (99% sure you cannot), you are out of luck. This doesn't mean you cannot mask, of course, but just that alpha channel masking will not work for you.

Comment: Wow, I was also 99% sure I wouldn't be able to - hence why I asked here. But you can cache FLV as a bitmap! Amazing. Thanks for making me try this. I'll have to check CPU/RAM though...

Comment: @James Roberts You can cache FLV as a bitmap? Glad I said 99%, then :)